# Laravel 5.2 query 1 table for postcode then grab ids and query another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to learn how to do a query. the search field is for postcodes which are stored inside of user_profiles (and user_profiles have a relationship with users)

So I have something that returns one result (however there are more than 1) but I heard doing 2 query's for one is bad

```
public function index()
{
    $queryUsername = Request::get('username');
    $queryPostcode = Request::get('postcode');
    if ($queryUsername) {
        $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%$queryUsername%")->get();
    }
    if ($queryPostcode) {

        $usersInfo = UserProfile::where('postcode', '=', "$queryPostcode")->value('user_id');
        $users = User::where('id', '=', "$usersInfo")->get();
    }
    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the question referenced better way is to go with join instead of two different queries

```
public function index()
{
    $queryUsername = Request::get('username');
    $queryPostcode = Request::get('postcode');
    if ($queryUsername) {
        $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%$queryUsername%")->get();
    }
    if ($queryPostcode) {

        $users = Users::rightJoin('user_profiles','users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
            ->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', "$queryPostcode")
            ->select(\DB::raw('users.*'))
            ->get();
    }
    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

if you are looking for an exact match of username
its not good to use LIKE for username matching 
  $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%$queryUsername%")->get();
because for usernames chris and chrisgeorge and christy the query %chris% will work and you wont get the exact match so recommend to use '=' instead of like

Comment: Holy crap you are a godsend! thanks so much!! I was doing left joins and trying joins but did not have any idea how to sort it out!  Although there was no need for the ->select(\DB::raw('users.*'))

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public function index(){
    $queryUsername = Request::get('username');
    $queryPostcode = Request::get('postcode');
    if ($queryUsername):
        $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%".$queryUsername."%")->get();
    elseif ($queryPostcode):

        $usersInfo = UserProfile::where('postcode', '=', $queryPostcode)->value('user_id');
        $users = User::where('id', '=', "$usersInfo")->get();
    endif;

    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: For some reason this also only returns one result, >_<

Comment: I think this is because your querying by user_id and should be only one.